# SAP Function Listener in Muleosft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

Need help to configure Function Listener for SAP in Mulesoft.  Can anyone help for the cofiguration details including Gateway host, Gate service, Program Id, Connection count, Targeted function.  And who can share those details?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an IDOC which you want to listen then you can use **"Document Listener"** to Listen to an IDOC's. Below are the configuration you will have to specify.

If you want to listen to incomming BAPi function then use **"Function Listener"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, as the MuleSoft examples are inconsistent in the values used, so it's a bit of a guessing game as to how to configure them!

The Gateway Host is your SAP instance host machine, the Gateway Service happens to be 3300 on my host, and the Program ID is a value of your own choosing which you share with whomever is calling your IDoc server. (Be aware that if you want to receive a different IDoc with a different IDoc listener, you need to use a different Program ID.)

I got this to work yesterday for MATMAS05 IDoc.